# Typescript cannot call function inside class by instance

Tags: typescript, class

Can someone explain why this is wrong? splitval is most definitely a function. I created a stackblitz with the [code here- check console for error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwezn5)

function call:

```
[(this.filcol, this.strtrans)] = (d.trans as Transform).splitval();
```

Output:

> edit trans:{"val":"fil.SalesOrderNo=.slice(0,7)","note":""}
>   TypeError: d.trans.splitval is not a function

Class:

```
export class Transform {
  val: string;
  note: string;

  splitval(): [string, string] {
    try {
      let filcol = this.val.substr(0, this.val.indexOf("="));
      let strtrans = this.val.substr(this.val.indexOf("=") + 1);
      return [filcol, strtrans];
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("err shared model splitval:" + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in this question, not off-site. It makes the question self-contained, so it will have value even without the link

Comment: Wait, why do you think `d.trans` has that method? The value is `d.trans=JSON.parse('{"val":"fil.SalesOrderNo=.slice(0,7)","note":""}')`, so it *wouldn't* have any methods at all.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like `d.trans` isn't actually an instance of `Transform`. Look at the code where that object is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly use `as` operator. In TypeScript it means assertion. It is not going to convert an object to an instance of the class.

When you parse a JSON in the following line, as a result, you get a regular js object:

`d.trans=JSON.parse('{"val":"fil.SalesOrderNo=.slice(0,7)","note":""}')`

`(d.trans as Transform)` means to typescript that you are asserting that d.trans is an instance of Class Transform which is wrong because it is not.

Please consider the fixed code: [angular-7qxpyu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qxpyu)

Comment: Doesn't make sense even as type casting, as that would still rely on objects being compatible. You can't do `dog = new Dog()` then later cast it as `cat = <Cat> dog;` and expect to be able to call `cat.meow()` without errors.

Comment: Yea that is true

Comment: Sorry, Im still confused.... the type may be object but since it EXACTLY matches a Transform, why is casting to a Transform object problem?

Comment: It is a compile-time cast/assertion not a runtime cast/assertion

Comment: @AdamWolski so that means the 'as Transform' would enable autocomplete at the UI level, but not necessarily make certain the object is of type Transform at runtime, which is what the error is about?